# How to launch teams.exe with powershell

Tags: powershell

I've been trying to launch teams using powershell, i've succeeded launching teams using the destination path under the shortcut property, and then running it in powershell.

```
C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\Update.exe --processStart "Teams.exe"
```

But this only works for the local user, if i run the script with another user teams won't launch. i've storing the user in a variable.

```
$user = $env:UserName 

C:\Users\$user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\Update.exe --processStart "Teams.exe"
```

This doesn't work.
So my question how can I launch teams.exe (make it visible)?
I want to make it like how you can launch word with `start winword.exe`

Comment: You cannot launch Teams from another user installation. What is it what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to run a script that starts the teams app, regardless of computer and user, if its possible?

Comment: Teams has to installed for the user who want's to use/start it. And then you have it in your profile and you can use the same path.

Answer (score 2):

"%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Teams\Update.exe" --processStart "Teams.exe"

Answer (score 0):

You should get the variable for the App Data folder, not just the username. Otherwise, it won't work in situations where the user's profile folder is in a different location:

```
$user = "$($env:LOCALAPPDATA)\Microsoft\Teams\Update.exe --processStart `"Teams.exe`""
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be fixed by using the following format instead:

```
$user = $env:UserName
'C:\Users\'+$user+'\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\Update.exe --processStart "Teams.exe"'
```

Comment: The user's profile folder doesn't necessarily live in that location. It might not even be on the C: drive at all. This is especially true of the big enterprise environments more likely to push Teams out by default.  Instead, you should look for the %AppData% folder.